# android:layout_alignParentEnd doesn't work on API 14

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-relativelayout

This is the relative layout part of my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/headLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/headbg"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/head2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/d10dp"
        android:text="@string/archive"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/d20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/moreBtn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/d50sp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/d30sp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/d10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/show_btn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

On an avd that has api 19, it works perfectly. Textview is on the left end of the relative layout, while the imageview is on the right. But on an avd that has api 14, both are on the left end. Am i missing some tags for alighparentend to work or it just doesn't work on api 14?

Comment: Can you post your resulting layout?

Comment: if you know the end is on the right (for example an English only app) use `layout_alignParentRight` or for right to left languages use `layout_alignParentLeft` for multi language apps you could apply the correct setting problematically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simply because according to the documentation, `android:layout_alignParentEnd` was introduced in Api level 17.

Source:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_alignParentEnd

Answer (score 0):

As already answered [`layout_alignParentEnd` is only supported since API 17](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_alignParentEnd). Before, it should be ignored, but can cause crashes on certain devices. You should define a default style and override it for v17.

Another, more hacky approach is to use the `fitStyle` of image:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/moreBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="..."
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/d10dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/d10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:src="@drawable/show_btn" />
```